# I/O Signals and Handlers

Tags: c++, networking, signals

I want to designate a callback for UDP port such that every time a new packet arrives, a handler is called for it.

I know about using fcntl() to cause file descriptors to raise SIGIO, but let's say things aren't quite that simple.  I have an object A with socket a and an object B with socket b.  Socket a receives a new packet, and therefore raises a SIGIO.  This only affects object A, however, and has nothing to do with object B.

How can I ensure a specific function is called when a specific port receives a packet?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [Boost.ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) library. It is designed for asynchronous I/O.

Answer (score 1):

[Boost.Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/signals.html) or [Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/signals2.html) (thread-safe version) may be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I ensure a specific function is called when a
>   specific port receives a packet?

(By "port" here, I assume you metonymously mean the `S_IFSOCK` *file descriptor* that represents your UDP socket.)

You have ***many general options*** available for I/O-driven apps:  blocking reader threads, multiplexing with *select(2)* or *poll(2)* or similar, requesting signal notification (esp. using queuing real time signals and extra info in an `SA_SIGINFO` handler), asynchronous I/O via *aio_read(2)*.  See [here](http://codeidol.com/unix/unix-network-programming/I-O-Multiplexing-The--Functions/I-O-Models/) for a brief overview.

Better yet, ***use a third party library*** that abstracts away these messy details, like the elsewhere-mentioned Boost.ASIO or [libevent](http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/).

> Socket a receives a new packet, and therefore raises a SIGIO.
>   This only affects object A, however, and has nothing to do
>   with object B.

Well, not precisely.  Signals are delivered to ("handled by") a thread within a process, sometimes a thread of your choosing, and in that sense affect neither object A nor object B directly. :)  Do you perhaps mean that a plain `SIGIO` cannot discriminate "data ready" on socket A from that on socket B?

If so, then ***don't use a plain `SIGIO`***.  Under Linux, [*fcntl(`F_SETSIG`)*](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) and an `SA_SIGINFO` handler with real time signals are enough to discriminate one ready fd from another.

Comment: However, even if you use F_SETSIG, you still have the problem that you can't do anything of use from within a signal handler without running the risk of crashing horribly. Remember kids, Just Say No to signal handlers.

Comment: @bdonlan, I quite agree with your caution, but find your conclusion overly broad.  One may quite safely set a *volatile sig_atomic_t* flag or tickle a pipe from with a handler.  With careful signal masking, this is all an event- or signal-driven program needs.